# Replacement of Bitcoin's 'account' and 'listunspent'

Tags: accounts, balances, raw-transaction

I accept Bitcoin at my website. I use self-developed merchant, based on Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC calls. Now I also want to accept Ethereum. I downloaded geth and as I see it has absolutely different, counter-intuitive API.

1. I can't see any 'account' paradigm there. How can I map order id to address in Ethereum. I need to create additional database for mapping? Actually, I can't even manage how to create new addresses for every order. What method I have to use?
2. What methods I need to use instead of `ListUnspent`, `CreateRawTransaction`, `SignRawTransaction` and `SendRawTransaction`?

Comment: I would recommend using [shapeshift](https://info.shapeshift.io/api) api

Comment: What's wrong with creating new addresses for every order? And maybe elaborate what you need `listunspent` for? Ethereum is a different technology and you need to re-implement everything if you prefer a self-developed solution.

Comment: Instead of creating a new address via RPC for each order, why don't you take advantage of Ethereum's smart contracts? You can pretty easily make a contract which generates a new address for each order, and automatically deals with managing payment status and order number